# How to Increment the Table Value With Max ID from Another Table

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a table like this: 
Tb_server

```
ID 
5 
6 
7
```

Tb_upload

```
ID 
1 
2 
3
```

I need a query which can update all the ID of Tb_server to `max(Tb_upload.ID) + 1` 
So, the result on the Tb_server should be like this

```
Tb_server   
ID   
4   
5   
6
```

I am doing this in a shell script, so I can get the `max(Tb_upload.ID)` as a variable. 
But what will be the query, using MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Tb_server, (SELECT @auto:=0) a 
SET ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Tb_upload) + (@auto:= @auto+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the max+1 of Tb_upload which is : 4

Make the update as :

```
update Tb_server  set Tb_serverID= (Tb_serverID+4);    // 4 is the difference here
```

Comment: The start Id's are 1(for Tb_upload) and 4(for Tb_server). I could not understand ur reply

Comment: You want Tb_serverID to increase be 1 as in your example right?

Comment: Ignore the above comment.I want the Tb_server ID to  become the max(Tb_uploadID)+1. In case If I have 7,8,9 in Tb_server it should become 4,5,6. Basically all the Id will be in serial after Tb_upload ID.